# send and get parameter between vuex and node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuex

I am using vuex to send parameter and query to node js, but I can get only the query and cannot get the parameter.

**This is my code on vuex**

```
Save_Alert_Detail: (commit, params) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var i = 0;
    if (params.params == 'curr_bal_not_equal_real_bal') {
      for (i; i < params.data.length; i++) {
        var data1 = {
          account_no: params.data[i].CUST_AC_NO,
          account_desc: params.data[i].AC_DESC,
          currency: params.data[i].CCY,
          account_cb: params.data[i].ACY_CURR_BALANCE,
          account_rb: params.data[i].REAL_BALANCE,
          differance: params.data[i].DIFF
        },
        var parameter=params.params
        axios({
          method: 'GET',
          url: datalink + '/post/alert_Detail',
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          query: data1,
          params: parameter,
        }).then(
          response => {
            resolve(response.data)
          }
        ).catch(error => {
          reject(error)
        })
      }
    }
```

**this is the path on nodejs**

```
const getcontrol=require("./controler")
router.get('/post/alert_Detail',getcontrol.postALertDetail)
```

**and I use console.log on controler to display the request like this**

```
exports.postALertDetail=(req,res,next)=>{
   console.log(req)
}
```

**and this is what I get from console.log**

```
params: {},


 query: {
    account_no: '05302210001185',
    account_desc: 'TRAN TRONG TAN ',
    currency: 'THB',
    account_cb: '-54,546.68',
    account_rb: '-54,546.68',
    differance: '0'
  },
```

**params** is null. please help me.

Comment: welcome. could you show how you use Save_Alert_Detail action?

Comment: do you mean  this one

Comment: Save_Detail:function(storefuntion){
      this.$store.dispatch("Save_Alert_Detail",{data:this.items,params:storefuntion})
    }

Comment: please remove the last two comments, and add the last comment to your post

Comment: Why aren't you doing this as a `POST` request?

Comment: be cause i want to get the response after insert data.

Answer (score 0):

[your code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lM6R.png)

Please check on above screenshot link.
I am not sure what is the value you want to pass to params. But according to screenshot above, looks like you are passing a string to params.

According to axios documentation https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/README.md

Params "Must be a plain object or a URLSearchParams object"

[axios documentation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mGde.png)

So, try passing an object instead of string to params.